Изменить спрайт в параллелограмм. Monogame
Мне нужно растянуть текстуру в форме параллелограмма. Это нужно чтобы потом это выглядело как 3д объект, но при этом без использования 3д. То биж грубо говоря собрать из нескольких спрайтов в 1)  чтобы спрайт "растянулся" как на фото. Есть ли способ это сделать без использования шейдеров?


По-английски это называется skew https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401741

Да, конечно можно без шуйдеров. Т.е. вы хотите прямоугольник растянуть и нарисовать параллелограммом в плоской 2D картинке, или чтобы он эту форму в 3D принял?

@andreymal подскажите кстати, а skew это обычно паралелограммное растяжение, или трапециообразное тоже?

@Kromster а в таких тонкостях терминологии мне разбираться лень)

@andreymal вот и мне кажется, что может быть другое название )

@Kromster ну я своровал термин из классики) https://content.instructables.com/FY7/PF7G/FCHYO30A/FY7PF7GFCHYO30A.jpg

@Kromster мне нужно растянуть текстуру в форме параллелограмма. Это нужно чтобы потом это выглядело как 3д объект, но при этом без использования 3д. То биж грубо говоря собрать из нескольких спрайтов в 1)

@andreymal спасибо, этот ответ выглядит так как мне и нужно!

Спасибо @andreymal за ссылку!
Если кому надо, то вот рабочий скрипт который был мне так нужен!
Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(60)) * 
            Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(30)) * 
            Matrix.CreateScale(1,1,0);

        _spritePlayer.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, matrix);
        _spritePlayer.Draw(Ваша текстура, new Vector2(50,50), Color.White);
        _spritePlayer.End();

